# css query for selecting div element which does not contain table element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, jsoup

i need to select div element outside the table ie.text '**Required Address**'

If i am using **main div[itemprop="address"]** i am getting all the 8 address

I want to uniquely identify the required div without containing table as parent

**Html:**

```
<main>
  <div>
    <div itemprop="address">Required Address</div>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr><td>
          <div itemprop="address">Address1</div>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
          <div itemprop="address">Address2</div>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
          <div itemprop="address">Address3</div>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
          <div itemprop="address">Address4</div>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
          <div itemprop="address">Address5</div>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
          <div itemprop="address">Address6</div>
        </td></tr>    
        <tr><td>
          <div itemprop="address">Address7</div>
        </td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use child selectors here:

```
doc.select("main > div > div[itemprop='address']");
```

Comment: We can also try a more fancy selector if Jsoup support `not()` --> `:not(td) > [itemprop="address"]`

Answer (score 2):

Use `>` operator.The styling will only apply to div provided if it has a parent div and also main as a parent tag.

```css
main > div > div[itemprop="address"] {

color: blue

}
```

```html
<main>
  <div>
    <div itemprop="address">Required Address</div>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr><td>
          <div itemprop="address">Address1</div>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
          <div itemprop="address">Address2</div>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
          <div itemprop="address">Address3</div>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
          <div itemprop="address">Address4</div>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
          <div itemprop="address">Address5</div>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
          <div itemprop="address">Address6</div>
        </td></tr>    
        <tr><td>
          <div itemprop="address">Address7</div>
        </td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use an `id` for this, if this is not an option for your use case.

```
main div > div[itemprop="address"] {
  // some code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can set (in this case) the color for the generic div and roll it back for those divs that are inside the table tag.

```css
div[itemprop="address"] {
  color: red;
}

table div[itemprop="address"] {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div>
    <div itemprop="address">Required Address</div>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div itemprop="address">Address1</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div itemprop="address">Address2</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div itemprop="address">Address3</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div itemprop="address">Address4</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div itemprop="address">Address5</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div itemprop="address">Address6</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div itemprop="address">Address7</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: This won't be of use in jsoup (or any other web scraping library), though, judging by the tags under the question.